# Access scope data after Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, google-calendar-api, angularfire2, google-api-js-client

I authorized the calendar api in my google sign in auth, using the following code (Angularfire2):

```
let auth = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
    this.afAuth.auth
      .signInWithPopup(auth).then((data) => {
        console.log(data); // nothing about calendar here
      });
```

Is there any way to access authorized scopes using FirebaseAuth?

For example, access the calendar data after the user signs and authorizes the calendar auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/), you'll see that there are  [examples for each provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider), which demonstrate how to obtain the third-party OAuth token:

```
// Using a redirect.
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  }
  var user = result.user;
});
```

Once you have the third-party token, you can use that directly against their APIs.

Comment: Hey @Kato, in this example I can get the accessToken only when the user logs in, but how I can retrive it later? I mean, if user refreshes the page and he is already logged in there is no way to retrive this token without re-signing? (unless saved to database, which may be a bad practise..)

Comment: What would you do with the token if you logged in with Google OAuth directly? You would still need to track it in some way. If I recall correctly, you should store the refresh token. They're really not the same auth creds, so if you need to be authenticated to Google APIs then do so. Note that you can always invert the process and pass that token to Firebase instead. But Firebase doesn't do any magic for managing your third-party provider auths.

Comment: hey @Kato Is it safe to save the access token onto the currentUser object?

Comment: Access tokens expire quickly so saving them isn't really useful. That's all managed by Firebase behind the scenes in most use cases.

Comment: @Kato looks like firebase auth does NOT refresh google access token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49946656/35634

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I said. Use Google OAuth directly if you need access to the refresh token.