# How to get refresh token for google api using Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

From firebase's documentation

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the 
Google API.
var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
var user = result.user;
// ...
}).catch(function(error) {
 // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
// The email of the user's account used.
var email = error.email;
// The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
var credential = error.credential;
// ...
});
```

Is there anyway I can get the refresh token for google api using firebase authentication. I couldn't find anything about this problem in Firebase's documentation. I am also aware that the `User` object also contains a `refreshToken`. Can I use that `refreshToken` from `firebase` to generate a new `access_token` for google api ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase Auth is currently focused on AuthN and not AuthZ. They do not manage OAuth tokens on sign in. All OAuth refresh tokens are discarded and only the initial OAuth access token is returned. If you need a Google refresh token, or a Google access token continuously, consider using [`GApi` library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people) to get a Google ID token/access token and then sign in with that to Firebase.

```
function onGoogleSignIn(googleUser) {
  var googleIdToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken));
}
```

You will always have the ability to get a Google OAuth access token from the Google sign in library that way.

Comment: From my understanding, doing auth this way also requires a backend implementation for exchanging the authorization code for tokens since we would have to use the `code` auth type.

Comment: The GApi library takes care of the token refresh for you. You don't necessarily need a backend implementation unless you need to do stuff on the backend (call Google APIs from the backend).

Comment: How would I get my access token back after a user turns to the app?

Comment: If you mean client side, the GApi library provides a way to get a fresh access token via AuthResponse whenever you need it: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse

Comment: Wow I completely missed that, I thought we would have to do the exchanging on our own. Do you know what is happening behind the scenes for this? My understanding is you need the refresh token / to get a new access token. Does the client library handle storing the refresh token for us and does the calls to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to get a new access token?

Comment: Yup. That is correct. They handle that for you and refresh tokens whenever they expire for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really saved me a ton of time from implementing this flow myself. 

I have another question, if I wanted to make background calls to a users data while they are away from the app, what would be the ideal way of doing it? For my case, I want to grab step counts a few minutes before a scheduled check.

I was thinking of using a web service worker to fetch the data client side and post to the firestore, so my cloud function just has do a step count comparison.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189903/discussion-between-william-chou-and-bojeil).

Comment: Any possibility to post the answer to your last question here @WilliamChou?

Comment: Actually found this github page and this NPM package. There is a full example here: https://github.com/msukmanowsky/gapi-firebase and package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-script

Comment: I ended up making a blog post about this https://github.com/wichopy/serverless-oauth2-blog-post